# use macro to extract several object fields in Julia

Tags: macros, field, julia

I have a structure, from which I want to access repeatedly the fields to I load them in the current space like this (where M is type with fields X and Y):

```
X = M.X
Y = M.Y
```

in R, I often use the `with` command to do that. For now I would just like to be able to have a macro that expends that code, something along the lines of

```
@attach(M,[:X,:Y])
```

I am just not sure how exactly to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've included in this answer a macro that does pretty much what you describe. Comments explaining what's going on are inline.

```
macro attach(struct, fields...)
    # we want to build up a block of expressions.
    block = Expr(:block)
    for f in fields
        # each expression in the block consists of
        # the fieldname = struct.fieldname
        e = :($f = $struct.$f)
        # add this new expression to our block
        push!(block.args, e)
    end
    # now escape the evaled block so that the
    # new variable declarations get declared in the surrounding scope.
    return esc(:($block))
end
```

You use it like this: `@attach M, X, Y`

you can see the generated code like so: `macroexpand(:(@attach M, X, Y))` which will show something like this:

```
quote
    X = M.X
    Y = M.Y
end
```

Comment: Beautiful, this is amazing. There are some tricks in there that I think would have taken me ages to figure out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: my pleasure. My first encounter with macros in julia were highly unintuitive so I'm glad I was able to save you some of that pain :-)

Comment: Here is a video that explains part of what is going here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpNeNCGmyZE

Comment: Does this still work in Julia 1.4 ?