# Access fields of struct using a macro

Tags: macros, julia

I would like to have a macro that is similar to the `@.` macro that converts every variable in an expression into a field of a struct. For example `x = y+z` should become `s.x = s.y + s.z` where `s`is an instance of a struct  `s = S(1,2,3)` with

```
struct S
x::Int
y::Int
z::float
end
```

I have found something similar in this question

[use macro to extract several object fields in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295960/use-macro-to-extract-several-object-fields-in-julia)

However it does not seem to work in my version of julia for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

##### Accessing a struct's properties

The package [PropertyUtils.jl](https://github.com/joshday/PropertyUtils.jl) has a `@with` macro that allows you do to this for value *access*:

```
julia> struct S
         x::Int
         y::Int
         z::Float64
       end

julia> s = S(1, 42, 3.14)
S(1, 42, 3.14)

julia> using PropertyUtils

julia> @with s begin
         x * y - z
       end
38.86
```

##### Using non-struct-member variables

If the expression contains a variable name that's not a property of the `struct`, then it's automatically treated as a normal variable.

```
julia> n = 100
100

julia> @with s begin
         x * y - z + n
       end
138.86
```

##### Modifying the struct members

However, you can't assign to the `struct`'s fields using this. `x = y + z` will define a new *variable* called `x` and assign to it, not to `s.x`.

You can instead return the values you want to be assigned to the struct's fields from the `@with` block, and assign to them from that:

```
julia> mutable struct MS
         x::Int
         y::Int
         z::Float64
       end #we need a mutable struct as we want to assign to its fields

julia> mut = MS(1, 42, 3.14)
MS(1, 42, 3.14)

julia> mut.z, mut.x = @with mut let
         _z = x * y - z + n
         _x = round(y + z)
         (_z, _x)
       end
(138.86, 45.0)

julia> mut
MS(45, 42, 138.86)
```